# Testng test-output folder

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Everytime when we run testng tests, we will manually refresh the project to get the test-ouput file right, I need to do this from with the code itself.  Without manually refreshing each time. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?
Thanks gptester

Comment: You have to refresh the project just to reflect the folder in project structure of your IDE. What do you want to do through your code?

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about a project in the Eclipse IDE here?

Comment: exactly right Gimby.  I'm working on a project and the requirement is to auto generate customised report from the testng.xml file. They do not need the report generated by testng.  So, I developed a code to read the testng results file and generate a xlsx file.  To read this testng.xml, I have to refresh the project everytime after each run.  Requirement is just run the suite file, once completed, read the testng-results.xml and generate the report without human intervention.  did i confuse you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can directly refer the output-folder location on hard-drive (eg. c:\project\test-output). It will have fresh test-output files after every test runs.